# Click command default arguments and/or options

Tags: python, python-click

There are a few `click` commands I'd like to put the same argument(s) on. Normally, this would look like this:

```py
@click.command()
@click.argument("arg", help="This is my argument")
def cmd1(arg):
    # ...
    do_something
    # ...

@click.command()
@click.argument("arg", help="This is my argument")
def cmd2(arg):
    # ...
    do_something_else
    # ...
```

Obviously, there is repetition here, which I would like to remove. Yes, the arguments will have the same name and help string. I came up with this, but I don't know if it's the right way to do it:

```py
import click


class FooCommand(click.Command):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.params.append(
            click.Argument(["foo"])
        )


@click.group()
def main():
    pass


@main.command(cls=FooCommand)
def cmd1():
    print("cmd1")


@main.command()
def cmd2():
    print("cmd2")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from click.testing import CliRunner

    runner = CliRunner()

    print("A FooCommand needs an argument")
    print(runner.invoke(main, ["cmd1"]).output)

    print("A normal Command does not")
    print(runner.invoke(main, ["cmd2"]).output)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution for single arguments or options seems to be to just create a variable `ARG = click.option(...)` and then use `@ARG` as a decorator of the command function.

Applying multiple opts/args at once involves creating a decorator factory or a callable class. This is the cleanest solution I found, credits go to `@altendky` and `@SnoopJ` from `#python` channel on Libera IRC:

```py
from typing import List, Callable

import attr
import click

from click.decorators import FC

options = [
    click.option("-a"),
    click.option("-b"),
]


# Solution 1: decorator factory
def multi_decorator(options: List[Callable[[FC], FC]]) -> Callable[[FC], FC]:
    def decorator(f: FC) -> FC:
        for option in reversed(options):
            f = option(f)

        return f

    return decorator


@click.command()
@multi_decorator(options)
def cmd1(a, b):
    pass


# Solution 2: callable class
@attr.s
class MultiDecorator:
    options: List[Callable[[FC], FC]] = attr.ib(factory=list)

    def __call__(self, f: FC):
        for option in reversed(self.options):
            f = option(f)

        return f


@click.command()
@MultiDecorator(options)
def cmd2(a, b):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from click.testing import CliRunner
    runner = CliRunner()

    print(runner.invoke(cmd1, ["--help"]).output)
    print(runner.invoke(cmd2, ["--help"]).output)
```

If you want to test or improve this, head over to https://replit.com/@ldericher/multidecorator.

Comment: In addition, I often make functions like `def create_some_option(default=29) -> click.Option:` if I want an option that is mostly the same but varies in some way between the different uses.  In this case you could set a different default.  It can be applied as `@create_some_option(default=13)`.